# How can I reconstruct a JSON array from a slice using lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I would like to extract a slice of a JSON array using lenses, and get a `Value` back. More specifically, I am trying to do the following:

```
$ import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
$ import Data.Aeson.Lens
$ import Control.Lens
$ let e = "{\"headers\":[[\"Host\",\"localhost:9090\"],[\"Accept-Encoding\",\"gzip\"]]}" :: LBS.ByteString
$ e ^? key "headers" . nth 0 . _Array . sliced 0 2
$ Just [String "Host",String "localhost:9090"]
```

It works but I would like the result to be a `Value` and not a `List`. How can I "reconstruct" a JSON array as part of the lens expression?

Comment: Could you please include imports?

Comment: @robx it's the lens-aeson package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Array` is a `Prism`. This means you can invert it to get `re _Array :: AsValue t => Getter (Vector Value) t`.

```
e ^? key "headers" . nth 0 . _Array . sliced 0 2 . re _Array
```

You can also use `over` (or its alias `(%~)`):

```
e ^? key "headers" . nth 0 . to (over _Array (slice 0 2))
e ^? key "headers" . nth 0 . to (_Array %~ slice 0 2)
```

Comment: `re _Array`  adds `Contravariant f` to the context :(

Comment: the type of `%~` does not align correctly: Couldn't match type ‘vector-0.12.0.1:Data.Vector.Vector a0
                           -> f0 (vector-0.12.0.1:Data.Vector.Vector a0)’
                     with ‘vector-0.12.0.1:Data.Vector.Vector Value’`

Comment: I managed to get it working by adapting the type of the function, Thanks for the answer.